# Jquery fadeIn + toggleclass(hide)

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate, fadein

The effect I want is that (1) "abc" div isn't showing intially, (2) it fades in slowly on page load, (3) there is a button on the page that onclick toggles a "hide" class on the "abc" div, so that I can hide/show it.

The way I'm trying to achieve these things is:
(1) setting "abc" div to display: none; initially in my CSS
(2) using jquery fadeIn property
(3) have a button that toggles it

I know my button works for hide/show, before I put any jquery for the fadeIn in there.
I know the fadeIn works, because I can see it fade in
BUT something about these both together means that the button to hide/show doesn't work on the element when it's fading in like this, even though it worked before I ever set display: none; on it and tried the jquery.

Help please!

I tried to make a jsfiddle but it's not working entirely. But you can see the basics of the code I'm using: http://jsfiddle.net/3bSB2/4/

Here's part of it (this code is required so that I can include the jsfiddle:

```
$(window).on("load", function() {
  $(".abc").fadeIn(525);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's because `.fadeIn()` uses inline css.

to fixed your problem, add `!important` to your `display:none`
like this

```
.hide {
    display: none!important;
}
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3bSB2/5/)

or if you are just showing/hiding, with no additional css styles, you can just use `.toggle()` instead of `.toggleClass()` like this

```
$(".abc").toggle();
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4wtEa/)